# Auto refresh of UI control

Tags: delphi

I have a problem while using delphi.

In my UI, I have a label and 5 bottons. Clicking of the 5 buttons can change some status, which would affect the label caption.

The OnClick function of the 5 buttons have already  implemented. So I need to add code to change to label caption in each of these functions.

This is not good. How to let the label auto changed the caption while checking the status? In VC, the label can get notify message priodically, can delphi do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `OnUpdate` event handler for an action, action list or action manager. These events are fired when the message loop completes processing of user input and becomes idle. That's perfect for your needs since the acts that lead to the change of the label caption are always a result of user input.

Another way to achieve the same effect would be to add a `TApplicationEvents` component to the form and update the label in a handler for that component's `OnIdle` event.

Comment: But TLabel has no action property

Comment: You don't need it to be on the label. On the buttons makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I make one, and connected the action to a button, it's ok.  But if I connect the action to the main form, then problem emerges: clicking the five labels one by one, after a while the app not response. It can accept key message, but not mouse.

Comment: I cannot see your code. I answered the question you asked I think.

Comment: Code is added to the question.

Comment: That code is completely unrelated to the question you asked. It's incomplete. It's just unfair to ask us to debug the code you write after we answer the question. You need to ask a new question to get help.